# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTables is not a function(…)

Tags: firebase, datatables

Database Admin Site

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>

    <script src="dialog-polyfill.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dialog-polyfill.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.green-cyan.min.css" />

    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js"></script>

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css" />

    <script type = "text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dbTable').dataTables();
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <table id = "dbTable"class="display mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp" cellspacing = "0" width = "100">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Email</th>
        <th>First Name </th>
        <th>Last Name </th>
        <th>Number </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id = "tableBodyObject" class="tableBodyClass">
      <!-- Table DATA //-->
    </tbody>
  </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" src = "index1.js"></script>

</body>
```

so when I run the code 
it shows in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTables is not a function(…)
```

Am using Firebase to create the table with the Firebase database, I tried using the datatables but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

It should be initialized with `dataTable()` (DataTables 1.9+) or `DataTable()` (DataTables 1.10+). See [Initializing DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#Initialising-DataTables) for more information.

There is also space missing between table `id` and `class` attributes, should be:

```
<table id="dbTable" class="display mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp" cellspacing="0" width="100">
```

Comment: So I tried doing this 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

then after the code I put this 

script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $("#dbTable").dataTable();
  })

it worked but the table is showing no data

Comment: @AdigaKnocker, also there is a space missing between table id and next attribute, should be `<table id="dbTable" class="...">`. Table in your example also has no data, make sure you include table rows.

Comment: The table data is coming from Firebase Database that's why there is no data in the HTML
The data is showing when I do it without the table pagination all the table data is showing perfectly! But I need to do as a pagination, when I do that the table for the pagination is empty and the Firebase data is under it

Comment: @AdigaKnocker, if your data is being loaded after the DataTable has already been initialised then that might be your issue. Either wrap you initialisation code within a setTimeout (not ideal) or look at adding your data after the table has been initialised. We could help you more but you'd perhaps need to let us see more of your solution... I'm guessing that your table rows were being added in `index1.js`? I'd guess that that adds rows to the table body...?

Comment: Yes am using tr.appendChild(snap.val()); So its adding the values in the rows from index1.js